# Bootstrap improve scaling on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a game releasing soon, and it's my first time making a webpage. It looks nice on desktops and my laptop, but the positions and size aren't showing as well on my phone.

Here's a mobile screenshot. The video size is kind of small. And the Contact/Email/Social media images are proportionally too large compared to the above content. I also don't like how everything is so cramped and fits in one view, eliminating scrolling.

[image]

There's also a problem with the page on my Mac Air using Chrome. The social media links don't show up at the bottom. Here's the bottom on Chrome. This problem doesn't occur when I'm viewing the page locally on my machine by opening the html file, only when I go to my website.

[image]

Edit: As suggested, here's the contents of my html/css files, instead of asking people to view the page source. Many thanks to whoever can help me with any of these things!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Risky Bee</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
    <img src="WebBG1a.jpg" style="display:none;"> 
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row">
        <img src=WebTrio3c.png class="img-responsive center-block">
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <img src=WebJuly21c.png class="img-responsive center-block" id="mar40">
      </div>

      <div class ="row" id="mar40">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FjtfCwNj8yU?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <img src=WebContactc.png class="img-responsive center-block" id="mar102">
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="img-responsive">
          <a href="mailto:support@riskybee.com" title="Email">
            <img src=WebEmailc.png class="center-block" id="mar25">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" id="mar20">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="img-responsive">
            <a href="https://facebook.com/RiskyBeeGame" title="Facebook">
              <img src=WebFacebook8c.png class="pull-right">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="img-responsive">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/riskybeegame" title="Twitter">
              <img src=WebTwitter7c.png>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/*
 * Base structure
 */
html {
  background: url(../WebBG1a.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  padding-top: 1.75%; /*1.75%*/
  padding-bottom: 1.75%; /*1.75%*/
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  background: transparent;
}

#mar20 { /*1.5%*/
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

#mar25 { /*1.75%*/
  margin-top: 1.75%;
}

#mar40 { /*2.75%*/
  margin-top: 2.75%;
}

#mar102 { /*8.6%*/
  margin-top: 8.6%;
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```

Edit #2:

I've got the video displaying better by doing the following:

```
  <div class ="row center-block rbvideo">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FjtfCwNj8yU?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But the width was too much on larger views, so I gave it a max width.

```
.rbvideo {
  margin-top: 40px;
  max-width: 750px;
}
```

I also changed the various margin spacing in my css file to px instead of percentage, which spread things out better when the view size decreased. Now I just have to figure out how to get the contact section to shrink a bit when the view gets smaller. Right now they stay the same size.

Regarding Chrome not showing the social media items, I finally realized it was AdBlock Plus blocking them. I've changed both image's filenames to not include "twitter" or "facebook" but they are still being blocked. Does someone know what I can do to prevent this? I've seen the same html code on other websites and ABP doesn't block them...

Comment: I know you've said it's live and people could view the source, however your page will change over time and any errors hopefully fixed which will leave people who come here in the future unable to see what your problem was and how you fixed it. More importantly for me, I'm on a mobile device and can't view the source :/

Comment: And of course, welcome to Stack Overflow!!! :D

Comment: so tell me more your exactly layout @MattH

Comment: You can see the ideal layout by visiting the website: riskybee.com on a desktop or laptop. I'm trying to make the mobile version (first image in the original post) more like the desktop and laptop versions. Specifically, making the video width match the release date width. And making the contact information's size in the first image more like the size in the second image. It looks goofy and enlarged on the mobile version.

Comment: In the absence of answers as at writing this it would appear to me your video is so small because offsetting your iframe by 2 columns. So you've got 4 columns missing on the small display. *edit: re margins*

Comment: I'm not fluent in bootstrap so I'm sure someone will come along shortly and correct it but the idea is you don't have the offset on xs devices and use all 12 columns,and then add the offset for the other relevant classes and use 8 columns on those devices.

Comment: Oh, I followed a different answer that suggested offsetting to align a column in the middle. I thought that meant moving it over, not removing columns. Is there a way I can center the video's col-xs-8 without removing columns?

Comment: well, you're not removing them, you're "skipping" them. Have a look here for some examples: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very crude example for you, since I've never really played with it before.

The essence of which is:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-5 col-md-2 test">
    <p align='center'>
    SOMETHING
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/madivad/s4jbyvL0/1/

In this example, devices fitting the smallest resolution "xs" will display the entire width (12 columns)

Those fitting the small "sm" range will utilise the middle 8, by offsetting the first two columns.

Medium "md" screens will be much smaller with 5 offset columns and being 2 columns wide

edit:

also, you're using the `id` tag for your top margins `#mar20` etc

These should be classes as well and just added to the class tag:
eg:

```
<div class="row mar20">
```

and in your CSS

```
.mar20{
    .... margin stuff
}
```

edit#2:

using the chrome inspector I just changed your code around the youtube embed and this works more as you expect, just modify to get it exactly how you'd prefer

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-8 col-centered">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FjtfCwNj8yU?rel=0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
</div>
```

edit for margins:
also, consider removing your margins for the smallest of devices. The following is exaggerated for illustration:

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.test {
  background-color: red;
}

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
  body{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  body{
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
  }
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  body{
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
  }
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
  body{
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
  }
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
  body{
    padding-left: 30%;
    padding-right: 30%;
  }
}
```

Comment: also it appears you fixed your social media tags, they appear correct in my chrome browser in OSX

Comment: sorry I'd forgotten to update the `jsfiddle` it's done now

Comment: Thanks for all the help you've given me. I changed all the ids to classes. I couldn't get the columns working, but I found another way to get the video displaying to my liking. I added a second edit to my original question detailing the improvements I've made. I guess it's personal preference, but I'd like to leave the padding on all views so there's some meat between the content and screen edges. Turns out AdBlockPlus is blocking my social media images, though I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing that's tripping the filter, as I've seen the same code on other websites display with no issues.

Comment: No problems, I got to learn more about bootstrap, which I've never really touched. *I wouldn't mind an upvote and tick for the answer though* ;)  ALSO: ask a new question about the social media icons, others will have the answer, and it is pretty simple. It has to do with the method and font face you're using, you can generate and tag these differently. Apparently it's more an adblock issue than one of the font. I'm happy to look into it, but as I said, I'm sure others have a quick and easy answer for you